# Why are my links not showing up via php email function?

Tags: php, mysql, html, email, header

I am trying to send notification emails(which is working fine) but have added the html headers to try to send links etc...for some reason nothing is showing up at all, just blank space where the desired links are supposed to be. Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['commentBlogSubmit']) && $auth) {

    $query = "SELECT `Email` FROM `Users` WHERE `id` = '" . $prof->id . "'";
    $request = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($request); 

    $Email = $result['Email'];


    $to = $Email;
    $subject = "Someone sent you left you a comment";
    $message = "You have a new blog comment  <br />".
               " <a href='http:www.blah.org/indexNew.php'></a>";
    $from = "info@blah.org";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
```

Comment: I reformatted the source code of your question so that one hasn't to scroll to see it whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the PHP email function generally sends plain text.

Rather than trying to do this yourself, you should probably use [Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime)

Also, though your headers are probably correct, you have nothing between the `<a>` and `</a>` tags.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps because you have no text inside the link tag?

Comment: duh! I can't believe I missed that! Thanks!

Comment: And after all: It's monday (at least in my part of the world). You're excused ;-).

Comment: Ha ha, I love mistakes like this. I do them all the time, it's nice to see that someone else's brain isn't working on a Monday either :-)

Comment: Haha this might be my fav question of the day.